# LET versus LET* in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I understand the difference between LET and LET* (parallel versus sequential binding), and as a theoretical matter it makes perfect sense.  But is there any case where you've ever actually needed LET?  In all of my Lisp code that I've looked at recently, you could replace every LET with LET* with no change.

Edit: OK, I understand *why* some guy invented LET*, presumably as a macro, way back when.  My question is, given that LET* exists, is there a reason for LET to stay around?  Have you written any actual Lisp code where a LET* would not work as well as a plain LET?

I don't buy the efficiency argument.  First, recognizing cases where LET* can be compiled into something as efficient as LET just doesn't seem that hard.  Second, there are lots of things in the CL spec that simply don't seem like they were designed around efficiency at all.  (When's the last time you saw a LOOP with type declarations?  Those are so hard to figure out I've never seen them used.)  Before Dick Gabriel's benchmarks of the late 1980's, CL *was* downright slow.

It looks like this is another case of backwards compatibility: wisely, nobody wanted to risk breaking something as fundamental as LET.  Which was my hunch, but it's comforting to hear that nobody has a stupidly-simple case I was missing where LET made a bunch of things ridiculously easier than LET*.

Comment: parallel is a poor choice of words; only previous bindings are
visible.  parallel binding would be more like Haskell's "... where ..." bindings.

Comment: I did not aim to confuse; I believe those are the words used by the spec.  :-)

Comment: Parallel is correct. It means that the bindings come to life at the same time and do not see each other and do not shadow each other. At no point does there exist a user-visible environment which includes some of the variables defined in the LET, but not others.

Comment: Haskells where bindings are more like letrec. They can see all the bindings on the same scope level.

Comment: Asking 'is there a case where `let` is needed?' is a bit like asking 'is there a case where functions with more than one argument are needed?'.  `let` & `let*` don't exist because of some notion of efficiency they exist because they allow humans to communicate intent to other humans when programming.

Comment: `let*` and `let` relate just like `setq` and `psetq` relate.

Answer (score 93):

`LET` itself is not a real primitive in a *Functional Programming Language*, since it can replaced with `LAMBDA`. Like this:

```
(let ((a1 b1) (a2 b2) ... (an bn))
  (some-code a1 a2 ... an))
```

is similar to

```
((lambda (a1 a2 ... an)
   (some-code a1 a2 ... an))
 b1 b2 ... bn)
```

But

```
(let* ((a1 b1) (a2 b2) ... (an bn))
  (some-code a1 a2 ... an))
```

is similar to

```
((lambda (a1)
    ((lambda (a2)
       ...
       ((lambda (an)
          (some-code a1 a2 ... an))
        bn))
      b2))
   b1)
```

You can imagine which is the simpler thing. `LET` and not `LET*`.

`LET` makes code understanding easier. One sees a bunch of bindings and one can read each binding individually without the need to understand the top-down/left-right flow of 'effects' (rebindings). Using `LET*` signals to the programmer (the one that reads code) that the bindings are not independent, but there is some kind of top-down flow - which complicates things.

Common Lisp has the rule that the values for the bindings in `LET` are computed left to right. Just how the values for a function call are evaluated - left to right. So, `LET` is the conceptually simpler statement and it should be used by default.

**Types in `LOOP`**? Are used quite often. There are some primitive forms of type declaration that are easy to remember. Example:

```
(LOOP FOR i FIXNUM BELOW (TRUNCATE n 2) do (something i))
```

Above declares the variable `i` to be a `fixnum`.

Richard P. Gabriel published his book on Lisp benchmarks in 1985 and at that time these benchmarks were also used with non-CL Lisps. Common Lisp itself was brand new in 1985 - the *CLtL1* book which described the language had just been published in 1984. No wonder the implementations were not very optimized at that time. The optimizations implemented were basically the same (or less) that the implementations before had (like MacLisp).

But for `LET` vs. `LET*` the main difference is that code using `LET` is easier to understand for humans, since the binding clauses are independent of each other - especially since it is bad style to take advantage of the left to right evaluation (not setting variables as a side effect).

Comment: No, no! Lambda is not a real primitive because it can be replaced with LET, and a lower-level lambda which just provides an API to get to the argument values:  `(low-level-lambda 2 (let ((x (car %args%)) (y (cadr args))) ...)`   :)

Comment: This answer does not ring true because the lambda parameters do not have initializing expressions which are evaluated in the surrounding environment. So that is to say `(lambda (a b c) ...)` is not specifically equivalent to `let` or `let*` in this regard. The `lambda` expression produces a run-time object, and the binding of the parameters is done late, when that object is invoked. The expressions which produce the values are in a totally different scope, perhaps another compiled file. [ continued ]

Comment: There is a situation in Common Lisp and similar dialects in which lambda parameters **do** have initializing expressions: `(lambda (&optional (a x) (b y) ...))`. **These optional parameters follow `let*` sequential binding, and not `let` parallel binding.**.  Thus, in summary, if we introduce optional parameters with default value expressions into `lambda`, then the issue of parallel versus sequential shows up, and it's just an implementation choice with pros and cons; neither is lower level or more fundamental than the other.

Answer (score 40):

You don't *need* LET, but you normally *want* it.

LET suggests that you're just doing standard parallel binding with nothing tricky going on.  LET* induces restrictions on the compiler and suggests to the user that there's a reason that sequential bindings are needed.  In terms of **style**, LET is better when you don't need the extra restrictions imposed by LET*.

It can be more efficient to use LET than LET* (depending on the compiler, optimizer, etc.):

- parallel bindings can be **executed in parallel** (but I don't know if any LISP systems actually do this, and the init forms must still be executed sequentially)
- parallel bindings create a single new environment (scope) for all the bindings.  Sequential bindings create a new nested environment for every single binding.  Parallel bindings use **less memory** and have **faster variable lookup**.

(The above bullet points apply to Scheme, another LISP dialect.  clisp may differ.)

Comment: Note: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562975/313756) (and/or the linked section of hyperspec) for a bit of explanation on why your first pullet point is -- misleading, let's say.  The _bindings_ happen in parallel, but the _forms_ are executed sequentially -- per the spec.

Comment: parallel execution is not something the Common Lisp standard takes care of in any way. The faster variable lookup is also a myth.

Comment: The difference isn't just important to the compiler.  I use let and let* as hints to myself of what is going on.  When I see let in my code, I know the bindings are independent, and when I see let*, I know the bindings depend on each other.  But I only know that because I make sure to use let and let* consistently.

Answer (score 29):

I come bearing contrived examples. Compare the result of this:

```
(print (let ((c 1))
         (let ((c 2)
               (a (+ c 1)))
           a)))
```

with the result of running this:

```
(print (let ((c 1))
         (let* ((c 2)
                (a (+ c 1)))
           a)))
```

Comment: Care to develop why this is the case?

Comment: @John: in the first example, `a`'s binding refers to the outer value of `c`. In the second example, where `let*` allows bindings to refer to previous bindings, `a`'s binding refers to the inner value of `c`. Logan isn't lying about this being a contrived example, and it doesn't even pretend to be useful. Also, the indentation is nonstandard and misleading. In both, `a`'s binding should be one space over, to line up with `c`'s, and the 'body' of the inner `let` should be just two spaces in from the `let` itself.

Comment: This answer provides an important insight.  One would **specifically** use `let` when one wants to _avoid_ having secondary bindings (by which I simply mean not the first one) refer to the first binding, but you _do_ want to shadow a previous binding -- using the previous value of it for initializing one of your secondary bindings.

Comment: Although the indentation is off (and I can't edit it), this is the best example so far. When I look at (let ...) I know that *none* of the bindings are going to build off of each other and can be treated separately. When I'm looking at (let* ...) I always approach with caution and look very carefully at which bindings are being re-used. For this reason alone, it makes sense to always use (let) unless you absolutely need nesting.

Comment: (6 years later...) was the wrong and misleading indentation by design, intended as a *gotcha*? I'm inclined to edit it to fix it... Should I not?

Comment: Too bad this answer does not explain why this is the case or what is going on anyway.

Answer (score 11):

In LISP, there's often a desire to use the weakest possible constructs.  Some style guides will tell you to use `=` rather than `eql` when you know the compared items are numeric, for example.  The idea is often to specify what you mean rather than program the computer efficiently.

However, there can be actual efficiency improvements in saying only what you mean, and not using stronger constructs.  If you have initializations with `LET`, they can be executed in parallel, while `LET*` initializations have to be executed sequentially.  I don't know if any implementations will actually do that, but some may well in the future.

Comment: Good point.  Though since Lisp is such a high-level language, that just makes me wonder why "weakest possible constructs" is such a desired style in Lisp land.  You don't see Perl programmers saying "well, we don't *need* to use a regexp here..."  :-)

Comment: I don't know, but there's a definite style preference.  It's opposed somewhat by people (like me) who like to use the same form as much as possible (I almost never write setq instead of setf).  It may have something to do with an idea to say what you mean.

Comment: The `=` operator is neither stronger nor weaker than `eql`. It is a weaker test because `0` is equal to `0.0`. But it is also stronger because non-numeric arguments are rejected.

Comment: The principle you're referring to is to use the *strongest* applicable primitive, not the *weakest*. For instance, if the things being compared are symbols, use `eq`.  Or if you know that you're assigning to a symbolic place use `setq`.  However, this principle is also rejected my many Lisp programmers, who just want a high level language without premature optimization.

Comment: actually, [CLHS says](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/s_let_l.htm) "the *bindings* [are done] in parallel" but "the expressions *init-form-1*, *init-form-2*, and so on, [are evaluated] in [specific, left-to-right (or top-down)] order". So  the values must be calculated sequentially (bindings are established *after* all the values have been calculated). Makes sense, too, since RPLACD-like structure-mutation is part of the language and with true parallelism it'd become non-deterministic.

Answer (score 10):

The main difference in Common List between LET and LET* is that symbols in LET are bound in parallel and in LET* are bound sequentially. *Using LET does not allow the init-forms to be executed in parallel nor does it allow the order of the init-forms to be changed.* The reason is that Common Lisp allows functions to have side-effects. Therefore, the order of evaluation is important and is always left-to-right within a form. Thus, in LET, the init-forms are evaluated first, left-to-right, then the bindings are created, <s>left-to-right</s> in parallel. In LET*, the init-form is evaluated and then bound to the symbol in sequence, left-to-right.

[CLHS: Special Operator LET, LET*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm)

Comment: It seems like this answer is perhaps drawing some energy from being a response to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/555136/313756)?  Also, per the spec linked, the _bindings_ are said to be done in parallel in `LET`, even though you're correct to call out that the init-forms are executed in series.  Whether that has any practical difference in any extant implementation, I don't know.

Answer (score 10):

I was recently writing a function of two arguments, where the algorithm is expressed most clearly if we know which argument is larger.

```
(defun foo (a b)
  (let ((a (max a b))
        (b (min a b)))
    ; here we know b is not larger
    ...)
  ; we can use the original identities of a and b here
  ; (perhaps to determine the order of the results)
  ...)
```

Supposing `b` was larger, if we'd used `let*`, we would have accidentally set `a` and `b` to the same value.

Comment: Unless you need the values of x and y later on inside the outer `let`, this can be done more simply (and clearly) with: `(rotatef x y)` -- not a bad idea, but it still seems like a stretch.

Comment: That's true.  It might be more useful if x and y were special variables.

Answer (score 8):

i go one step further and use [bind](http://common-lisp.net/project/metabang-bind/user-guide.html) that unifies `let`, `let*`, `multiple-value-bind`, `destructuring-bind` etc., and it's even extensible.

generally i like using the "weakest construct", but not with `let` & friends because they just give noise to the code (subjectivity warning! no need to try convincing me of the opposite...)

Comment: Ooh, neat.  I'm going to go play with BIND now.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 6):

There is definitely an efficiency argument between `let` and `let*`. But the main reason why we have `let` is historic, due to the relationship with `lambda`.

`let` is easier, simpler and more efficient to implement **in a code-walking Lisp interpreter**. This is particularly true if there is some half decent data structure for environments, rather than just an `assoc` list.

Suppose that the interpreter implements environments as a chain of objects. So for instance `(let (a b) (let (c d) (let (e f))))` will add three environment nodes to the environment chain. Each of these new nodes contains two bindings (in an individual list, or hash table or whatever).

When we interpret the `let` form, we can evaluate all of the initializing expressions in the incoming environment chain. We can create a single environment node for all of the new bindings, in a single operation, and populate the bindings with the values.

When we interpret the `let*` form, we cannot do this. For each successive binding mentioned in the `let*`, we have to call `make-environment`, populate it, and add it to the environment chain, so that we then interpret the next initialization form in the extended environment.

This leads to a degenerate run-time environment structure. Whereas `(let (a b c d ...))` produces one environment object with a nice hash table in it, `(let* (a b c d ...))` produces an inefficient chain that requires O(n) traversal to find a binding.

We can erase the difference between the interpreter performance of `let` and `let*`, but only by dragging the performance of `let` down to `let*`. If we represent the environment chain as a naive `assoc` list, then this issue doesn't matter; all variable lookups are a linear search. In fact `let*` is then easier to implement: evaluate each init expression, and push a new binding onto the current environment.

**Now, enter compilation into the picture.**  A Lisp compiler can use a devilish trick to implement `let*` by just making a few tweaks to the compilation strategy for `let`.    To compile `let*`, we can allocate a single environment for all the bindings (a move which would result in incorrect scoping in the interpreter).  We leave that environment empty, and add it to the compile-time environment chain. We thus compile the init expressions in the scope of that new environment. As we iterate over the init expressions to compile them, we add each corresponding variable to that environment one by one, so that the compilation of subsequent init expressions will have that variable in scope.

`let*` is a simple hack that becomes obvious when you have a Lisp compiler that handles `let`.

A Lisp compiler easily produces efficient representations of environments, regardless of scoping rules, which is not necessarily true of an interpreter.

Since interpreters came first, that explains why `let` is parallel. At least partially. The other reason is that `let` was realized as a syntactic sugar over `lambda`. But `lambda` (originally) does not have initializing expressions at all in its own scope; it just specifies variables. The `lambda` expression produces a run-time object, such that the binding of the values to the parameters happens at run time, when the function is invoked. The evaluation of the argument expressions is in a totally different scope.

Now in the immediately-called `lambda`, this is still true: the scope of the expressions is entirely outside of the `lambda`:

```
((lambda (a b) (+ a b)) 1 2)
```

The expressions `1` and `2` have nothing to do with the `lambda`; they are not enclosed in it.

So it is obvious that if we want a `let` sugar notation which corresponds to the above, we must carefully preserve this property:

```
(let ((a 1) (b 2))
  (+ a b))
```

If we want this `let` to be the same as the previous `lambda`, we must make it look as if `a` and `b` are function parameters, and `1` and `2` are argument expressions.

If you're a researcher working with a language that has `lambda` and no `let`, longing for a nicer way to write immediately-called `lambda`s, it is unlikely that you will invent `let*` binding semantics. You will invent something that has a clear translation strategy to the existing construct you are using all over your code, so that you can refactor the code to use it without surprises.

Note that the modern `lambda` in dialects like Common Lisp **does** have embedded expressions in it: namely optional and keyword arguments!

```
(lambda (a &optional (b x) (c y) ...))
```

These default value expressions `x` and `y` are evaluated in the surrounding lexical scope, whenever the argument is missing, every time time the function is called. And, so, what scoping discipline do these expression use? Why, serial, not parallel!

```
[1]> (defun foo (x &optional (y (1+ x)) (z (1+ y)))
       (list x y z))
FOO
[2]> (foo 10)
(10 11 12)
```

So, things went full circle. In the beginning, there was `LAMBDA`. `LAMBDA` begat `LET`. `LET` begat `LET*`, and `LET*` begat newer `LAMBDA` with sequential binding for optional argument init-forms. :)

The result is that translating a modern immediately-called lambda into `let` is quite complicated. For instance:

```
(funcall (lambda (x y &optional (z x) (w (1+ z))) a b c)
```

can compile into:

```
 (let ((x a) (y b))   ;; we put the fixed params into a let
   (let* ((z c))      ;; z arg present, so refer to c, not x
          (w (1+ z))) ;; w arg absent, use (1+ z)
     ...))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(let ((list (cdr list))
      (pivot (car list)))
  ;quicksort
 )
```

Of course, this would work:

```
(let* ((rest (cdr list))
       (pivot (car list)))
  ;quicksort
 )
```

And this:

```
(let* ((pivot (car list))
       (list (cdr list)))
  ;quicksort
 )
```

But it's the thought that counts.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably by using `let` the compiler has more flexibility to reorder the code, perhaps for space or speed improvements.

Stylistically, using parallel bindings shows the intention that the bindings are grouped together; this is sometimes used in retaining dynamic bindings:

```
(let ((*PRINT-LEVEL* *PRINT-LEVEL*)
      (*PRINT-LENGTH* *PRINT-LENGTH*))
  (call-functions that muck with the above dynamic variables))
```

Comment: In 90% of the code, it makes no difference whether you use `LET` or `LET*`. So if you use `*`, you are adding an unnecessary glyph. If `LET*` was the parallel binder and `LET` were the serial binder, programmers would still use `LET`, and only pull out `LET*` when wanting parallel binding. This would likely make `LET*` rare.

Comment: actually, CLHS [specifies the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554949/let-versus-let-in-common-lisp/10036843#comment86208921_554994) of evaluation of let's *init-form*s.

Answer (score 3):

Under `let`, all of the variable initializing expressions see exactly the same lexical environment: that which surrounds the `let`. If those expressions happen to capture lexical closures, they can all share the same environment object.

Under `let*`, every initializing expression is in a different environment. For each successive expression, the environment must be extended to create a new one. At least in the abstract semantics, if closures are captured, they have different environment objects.

A `let*` must be well-optimized to collapse the unnecessary environment extensions in order to suitable as an everyday replacement for `let`. There has to be a compiler which works out which forms are accessing what and then converts all of the independent ones into larger, combined `let`.

(This is true even if `let*` is just a macro operator that emits cascaded `let` forms; the optimization is done on those cascaded `let`s).

You cannot implement `let*` as a single naive `let`, with hidden variable assignments to do the initializations because the lack of proper scoping will be revealed:

```
(let* ((a (+ 2 b))  ;; b is visible in surrounding env
       (b (+ 3 a)))
  forms)
```

If this is turned into

```
(let (a b)
  (setf a (+ 2 b)
        b (+ 3 a))
  forms)
```

it will not work in this case; the inner `b` is shadowing the outer `b` so we end up adding 2 to `nil`. This sort of transformation **can** be done if we alpha-rename all of these variables. The environment is then nicely flattened:

```
(let (#:g01 #:g02)
  (setf #:g01 (+ 2 b) ;; outer b, no problem
        #:g02 (+ 3 #:g01))
  alpha-renamed-forms) ;; a and b replaced by #:g01 and #:g02
```

For that we need to consider the debug support; if the programmer steps into this lexical scope with a debugger, do we want them dealing with `#:g01` instead of `a`.

So basically, `let*` is the complicated construct which has to be optimized well to perform as well as `let` in cases when it could reduce to `let`.

That alone wouldn't justify favoring `let` over `let*`. Let's assume we have a good compiler; why not use `let*` all the time?

As a general principle, we should favor higher-level constructs that make us productive and reduce mistakes, over error-prone lower-level constructs and rely as much as possible on good implementations of the higher-level constructs so that we rarely have to sacrifice their use for the sake of performance. That's why we are working in a language like Lisp in the first place.

That reasoning doesn't nicely apply to `let` versus `let*`, because `let*` is not clearly a higher level abstraction relative to `let`. They are about "equal level". With `let*`, you can introduce a bug that is solved by simply switching to `let`. And *vice versa*. `let*` really is just a mild syntactic sugar for visually collapsing `let` nesting, and not a significant new abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

With Let you use parallel binding,

```
(setq my-pi 3.1415)

(let ((my-pi 3) (old-pi my-pi))
     (list my-pi old-pi))
=> (3 3.1415)
```

And with Let* serial binding,

```
(setq my-pi 3.1415)

(let* ((my-pi 3) (old-pi my-pi))
     (list my-pi old-pi))
=> (3 3)
```

Comment: Yes, that is how they are defined.  But when would you need the former?  You're not actually writing a program that needs to change the value of pi in a particular order, I assume.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The OP enquires "ever actually needed LET"?

When Common Lisp was created there was a boat load of existing Lisp code in assorted dialects.  The brief the folks who designed Common Lisp accepted was to create a dialect of Lisp that would provide common ground.  They "needed" to make it easy and attractive to port existing code into Common Lisp. Leaving LET or LET* out of the language might have served some other virtues, but it would have ignored that key goal.

I use LET in preference to LET* because it tells the reader something about how the data flow is unfolding.   In my code, at least, if you see a LET* you know that values bound early will be used in a later binding.  Do I "need" to do that, no; but I think it's helpful.  That said I've read, rarely, code that defaults to LET* and the appearance of LET signals that the author really wanted it.  I.e. for example to swap meaning of two vars.

```
(let ((good bad)
     (bad good)
...)
```

There is debatable scenario that approaches 'actual need'.  It arises with macros.  This macro:

```
(defmacro M1 (a b c)
 `(let ((a ,a)
        (b ,b)
        (c ,c))
    (f a b c)))
```

works better than

```
(defmacro M2 (a b c)
  `(let* ((a ,a)
          (b ,b)
          (c ,c))
    (f a b c)))
```

since (M2 c b a) isn't going to work out.   But those macros are pretty sloppy for assorted reasons; so that undermines the 'actual need' argument.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Rainer Joswig's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554949/let-versus-let-in-common-lisp/587837#587837) answer, and from a purist or theoretical point of view. Let & Let* represent two programming paradigms; functional and sequential respectively.

As of to why should I just keep using Let* instead of Let, well, you are taking the fun out of me coming home and thinking in pure functional language, as opposed to sequential language where I spend most of my day working with :)

Answer (score -1):

I mostly use LET, unless I specifgically need LET*, but sometimes I write code that explicitly *needs* LET, usually when doing assorted (usually complicated) defaulting. Unfortunately, I do not have any handy code example at hand.

Answer (score -1):

who feels like re-writing letf vs letf* again? the number of unwind-protect calls?

easier to optimize sequential bindings.

maybe it effects the *env*?

allows continuations with dynamic extent?

sometimes (let (x y z)
               (setq z 0
                     y 1
                     x (+ (setq x 1)
                          (prog1
                   (+ x y)
                  (setq x (1- x)))))
    (values () ))

[ I think that works ] point is, simpler is easier to read sometimes.