# Why isn't let* the default let?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

As probably all experienced elispers have found at some point, code like is broken:

```
(let ((a 3)
      (b 4)
      (c (+ a b)))
  c)
```

One should use the `let*` form instead when referring to a just-binded variable within the binding clauses.

I just wonder - why is a seemingly wrong behavior the default? Are there any risks on choosing always `let*` regardless of how is one gonna use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was taught that the reason is mainly historical, but it might still hold: Since `let` does parallel assigment, having no data dependencies between the variables might give the compiler flexibility compile for speed or space and compile to something much faster than `let*`. I don't know how much the elisp compiler uses this.

A bit of googling reveals a similar question for Common Lisp: [LET versus LET* in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554949/let-versus-let-in-common-lisp)

Comment: +1 for parallel assignment. More important now in multicore environments, although I'm not sure many compilers take advantage of this.

Comment: I'm not sure about how the Elisp and CL compilers are really doing now, but the Hyperspec, a de facto standard reference for CL, [says differently](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/s_let_l.htm): "The form `(let ((var1 init-form-1) (var2 init-form-2) ...) ...)` first evaluates the expressions `init-form-1`, `init-form-1`, and so on, **in that order**, saving the resulting values."

Comment: Yes, its very subtle. The assigment is done in parallel, but the calculation of expressions is sequential. see this particular answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554949/let-versus-let-in-common-lisp/562975#562975. I wonder if this makes the performance-based argument really a myth or there is still some advantage to be taken from this relaxation.

Comment: This is an example where the sequential order matters: `(let ((y (setq x 1)) (z (setq x 2))) x)`. `let` is not so much free from data dependency.

Comment: For sure, I fully agree! Thats why I stated the reasons are mainly historical (it might have been different in a an early draft of the CL standard or in a different lisp). I'm asking though is what kind of better code can still the compiler generate for `let` that it *cannot* generate for `let*`. Maybe a different SO question?

Answer (score 23):

Any `let*` forms can be **easily** (and mechanically) expressed using `let`. For example, if we didn't have the `let*` special form, we could express

```
(let* ((a 3)
       (b 4)
       (c (+ a b)))
  c)
```

as:

```
(let ((a 3))
  (let ((b 4))
    (let ((c (+ a b)))
      c)))
```

On the other hand, some `let` forms are quite difficult, if possible at all, to express using `let*`. The following `let` form cannot be expressed using `let*` without introducing an additional temporary variable or esoteric bitwise manipulation.

```
(let ((x y) (y x)) ; swap x and y
  ...)
```

So, in this sense, I think `let` is more fundamental than `let*`.

Answer (score 4):

it is incorrect to do so

```
(let ((a 10)
      (b a)) <- error
  b)
```

it is correct to do so:

```
(let* ((a 10)
       (b a))
   b) <- will evaluate to 10.
```

The error in the first case is due to semantics of let.

`let*` adds new symbols to the existing environment, evaluating them inside it.

`let` creates a new environment, evaluating the new symbols in the current envinronemnt, and the new environment will be disponible at the end of the evaluation of all new symbols, to evaluate the code of (let () code ).

`let*` is syntactic sugar for

```
(let ((a xxx))
  (let ((b a)) ...)
```

while `let` is [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for

```
((lambda (a)
  ...)
  val_a)
```

**The second form is much more common**, so perhaps they thought to give it a shorter name...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I would call `let` broken. For instance, you may for whatever reason want to shadow `a` and `b` in the enclosed environment, while defining `c` with respect to the enclosing expression.

```
(let ((a 11)
      (b 12))
  (let ((a 3)
        (b 4)
        (c (+ a b)))
    ;; do stuff here will shadowed `a' and `b'
    c))
> 23
```

As for risks, I don't know if there are any per se. But why created multiple nested environments when you don't have to? There may be a performance penalty for doing so (I don't have enough experience with elisp to say).